# Noise Removal From Image Using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have performed the thinning operation on a binary image with the code provided [here](https://github.com/bsdnoobz/zhang-suen-thinning/blob/master/thinning.cpp). The source image which I used was this one.

[image: Source Image]

And the result image which I obtained after applying thinning operation on the source image was this one

[image: Result Image]

The problem I am facing is how to remove the noise in the image. Which is visible around the thinned white lines.

Answer (score 0):

In such particular case, the easiest and safest solution is to label the connected component (union-find algorithm), and delete the one with a surface lower than one or two pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple but perhaps not so robust is to use contour area to remove small connected regions, then use erode/dilate before applying thinning process.

However you can so process your thinned image directly by using cv::findContours(,) and mask about contours with small area. This is similar to what FiReTiTi answered.

You can use the [findContour](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) example from OpenCV to build a contour detection using edge detector such as [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny#canny). The example can be ported directly as part your requirment.

Once you got the contours in `vector<vector<Point> > contours;`you can iterate over each contour and use [cv::contourArea](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#contourarea) to find the area of each region. Using pre-defined threshold you can remove unwanted areas.

Comment: I modified my answer with few links to examples that can help you perhaps. Let me know if I can help further.

Comment: I will try it now and let you know in a while.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I have used the exact method you mentioned in your answer and it gave me the correct result.

Comment: One thing more my instructor has told me to use minutiae on the thinned image. Can you help me how to do it.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt get you. Can you specify in bit detail please.

Comment: Minutiae is used to find ridges and bifurcations. Which actually are points where one when is linked to other. I have to find these points . I have to do some thing like this which is described here [link](http://www.intechopen.com/books/biometrics/minutiae-based-fingerprint-extraction-and-recognition).

Comment: This features should not be really difficult to detect. I read few papers just to get the idea, and this paper describes the approch well. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Lin_Hong7/publication/3192878_Fingerprint_Image_Enhancement_Algorithm_and_Performance_Evaluation/links/54733a590cf24bc8ea19d08c.pdf . From page 8 there they describe there algorithm,

Answer (score 0):

FiReTiTi and kcc__ have already provided good answers, but I thought I'd provide another perspective.  Having looked through some of your previous posts, it appears that you're trying to build software that uses vascular patterns on the hand to identify people.  So at some point, you will need to build some kind of classification algorithm.

I bring this up because many such algorithms are quite robust in the presence of this kind of noise.  For example, if you intend to use supervised learning to train a convolutional neural net (which would be a reasonable approach assuming you can collect a decent amount of training samples), you may find that extensive pre-processing of this sort is unnecessary, and may even degrade the performance.

Just some thoughts to consider.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion why dont you use distance transform on the 1st image and then from the resultant image use size filter to de-speckle the image.